# C++: Using erase in a vector of iterators

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I'm experiencing a problem using the erase function in C++.

I have the following structure:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,TreeElement> ObjMap;
class TreeElement {
    public:
        ObjMap::const_iterator parent;
        std::vector<ObjMap::const_iterator > children;
}
```

Now I'm trying to remove a TreeElement from the list of children of its parent using the erase function.

```
//Remove from parent
SegmentMap::const_iterator parent = segment->second.parent;
std::vector<SegmentMap::const_iterator >::const_iterator it = parent->second.children.begin();
for(;((*it)->first != segment->first) && (it != parent->second.children.end()); it++);
parent->second.children.erase(it); //Compilation fails
```

This gives an error during compilation indicating it can't convert

```
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, TreeElement> >*, std::vector<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, TreeElement> > > >
```

to

```
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, TreeElement> >*, std::vector<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, TreeElement> > > >
```

Is there any way to fix this?
I tried using an iterator instead of a const_iterator but this just moved the compilation error to

```
std::vector<SegmentMap::const_iterator >::iterator it = parent->second.children.begin();
```

Clarification:
I know the erase function expects a non-const iterator. I'm looking for a way to create this non-const iterator without changing the declaration of *parent* and *children* in the TreeElement class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent is const iterator, therefore `parent->second` is const, therefore `parent->second.children` is const, therefore `parent->second.children.begin()` returns const iterator.

`erase` expects a non-const iterator.

Comment: And is there any way to create a non-const iterator without changing the declaration of parent?

Comment: @user1611565 nope. You could of course cast the `const` away, but that's very ugly. Why would you want to use const_interator anyway, there is nothing in the code preventing you to use normal iterator.

Comment: I'm currently adding methods to an existing system, in this case a delete method. I'm not supposed to change the TreeElement class.

Comment: @user1611565 Removing is changing.

Comment: I'm talking about changing the declaration of the variables that are already there. For example: I'm not supposed to change ObjMap::const_iterator parent; to ObjMap::iterator parent;

Comment: @user1611565 Well, then you by design, can't change the parent in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `erase()` when using `const_iterator`. The purpose of `const_iterator` is to prohibit modification of the `vector` in any way, including erasing elements through it. You should use simply `iterator` and then fix that compilation error.

Then that compilation error is because you are trying to assign a `const_iterator` to a non-const `iterator`. If you modify and make `parent` a non-const `iterator`, the error should go away.